# Webpack Tree Shaking not working as expected

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, tree-shaking

I've got a relatively simple library that I'm using Webpack to bundle. The library is made available on the `window`. I can't get tree shaking to work properly. I have to delete unused code for it to actually be tree shaken. Roughly, my code is structured something like this:

entry.js

```
import Formatters from './formatters/formatters';

export { Formatters };
```

formatters/formatters.js

```
import { formatAttribute, prettyPrint } from './formatters-internal';

const Formatters = {
  formatAttribute,
  prettyPrint,
};

export { Formatters as default };
```

and formatters/formatters-internal.js

```
import prettyFormat from 'pretty-format';

export function prettyPrint(val) {
  return prettyFormat(val);
}

export function formatAttribute(object, key='test') {
  if (!object[key]) {
    return '';
  }
  return `${object[key]}`;
}
```

In `formatters.js`, I would expect that when I delete `prettyPrint` from the `import` statement and the `Formatters` object, the `pretty-format` dependency is not included in my bundle. This isn't the case. It's still part of the bundle. I have to go into `formatters-internal` and actually delete the `prettyPrint` function for it to be shaken out. Because of how this application will be used, simply deleting things from `formatters-internal` is not an option. Here's what my Webpack config looks like:

```
module.exports = function () {
  return {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: {
      'bundle': './src/entry.js'
    },
    output: {
      filename: '[name].js',
      library: 'SomeLibrary',
      libraryTarget: 'window'
    }
  }
};
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Babel is not being used to convert things to CommonJS. I also made sure that my package.json (and the package.json of `pretty-format`) has `"sideEffects: false"`.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what you actually use is [pretty-format](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-format) or [pretty-print](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pretty-print)? because you said _"... the pretty-print dependency is not included in my bundle"_ and also _"... the package.json of pretty-print) has "sideEffects: false""_ but on `formatters-internal.js` you use pretty-format.

Comment: Sorry, corrected the post! pretty-format is the 3rd party library used.